# Finding the integer index in a datetime-indexed dataframe for certain conditions

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas.DataFrame object that looks something like the following:

```
 DateTime              t      a      b      c
 ...                   ...    ...    ...    ...
 2016-06-19 21:43:00   2422   2420   2425   2
 2016-06-19 21:43:00   2423   2420   2425   2
 2016-06-19 21:43:00   2424   2420   2425   2
 2016-06-19 21:43:00   2425   2420   2425   2
 2016-06-19 21:43:01   2424   2422   2424   1
 2016-06-19 21:43:02   2423   2422   2424   3
 2016-06-19 21:43:02   2424   2422   2424   3
 ...                   ...    ...    ...    ...
```

And also, let's say that this section of the dataframe is equal to rows 1000 through 1006 (i.e. `df.iloc[1000:1006]`). I would like to return the integer index of a row of this dataframe where the following conditions hold true:

- the "c" column is a 3
- the "t" column is a local maximum
- the integer index is between 1004 and 1006.

I believe that you can simply use the `np.where` function to return the indices where the 'c' column is a 3, but I'm having trouble filtering these results to have it such that the 't' column is a local max and the integer index is between x and y. In this case, I'd like to be given the index 1006 (because 't' is maximum, 'c' is 3, and this integer, 1006, is between 1000 and 1006).

If anyone has any ideas on how to efficiently do this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!